# Getting driver license in Washington state when moving from Canada (BC)

Tags: usa, canada, driving-licenses, british-columbia, washington-state

I live in BC, Canada and have Class 5 driver license. I want to move to the USA (state Washington) in H1-B status and wondering how I can get US driver license. I heard that there is some kind of agreement between BC and Washington state and no exams or tests needed, so it is simple exchange. Is it true?

Comment: @Vitality - welcome.  As per the other question you asked as well, this is really an immigration question.  If you reword it to be travel related, we could reopen it, but as it stands it's currently off topic.

Comment: @Mark, since the Immigration petition failed, maybe it should still be allowed here?

Comment: @littleadv - fortunately there's still the [Expat Proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38732/expatriates)

Comment: yep, signed up for that one too. Hopefully will get enough votes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is true. The State of Washington has similar agreements with British Columbia, Germany and Korea.

As long as your BC license is valid, you can follow the procedures same to the people holding an out-of-state US license. See [here](http://www.dol.wa.gov/driverslicense/moving.html). This is only for British Columbia licenses, other Canadian licenses holders should take the test.